# Porting GCC to new architectures

Tags: architecture, gcc, porting, cross-compiling

How do I go about porting gcc to a new architecture? I am specifically interested in the following architectures:

- ARM (TI OMAPs)
- TI MSP430
- x86

but guidance on how to port to any architecture would go some way to solving my problem.

Comment: I am good with ARM (TI OMAPs), TI MSP430 and x86 architectures

Comment: Duplicate of the OP's earlier question, [Porting GCC to new architectures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245234/porting-gcc-to-new-architectures). Improve your existing question, don't repost.

Comment: You're asking this for the third time already. The two earlier questions where closed. So why do you think it will not this time ? Also I think we're not the right audience for this. If you really want/need to do this you should ask on the GCC mailing list.

Comment: whats the problem with my question? is there any thing wrong please suggest.

Comment: Also, GCC already supports ARM and x86 just fine, and [MSP430 as well](http://mspgcc4.sourceforge.net/). So to which architecture do you want to port GCC ?

Comment: @srikanthM: The question is too broad. To answer this, one could write a whole *book*. It cannot be reasonably answered with a few hundred words. Please go to the GCC mailing list and ask for assistance and guidance there, they can tell you where to start, what to read, what to study.

Comment: @srikanthM Think of SO as having referential transparency. If you ask an inappropriate question once and it gets closed, it's going to get closed again. And again. And... Ah, yes, again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Learning to port gcc is going to be a significantly non-trivial task. As a rough guide of what to expect, you will need to know:

- The target architecture inside out. Literally, otherwise how else will you know how to convert C to it?
- The C standard, so C89, C99 etc.
- How compilers work. There are whole books on this.

In order to start the process, you would typically start with the C-to-assembly translation on your host architecture, such that you could compile something for the target architecture (but on your host). You would then get to the stage where you can compile a compiler for your target architecture on your host. At this stage, you produce a compiler on the target which can then self-compile, so you now have gcc on the target.

Once this work has been done, actually porting gcc is simply a case of building gcc from the host on the target. If that's all you're interested in, [Linux from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/) is a very good guide for doing everything you'll need to do (as gcc would, amongst other things, be a prerequisite for porting the kernel).

Comment: And what if the target host had a different instruction set then x86-64/i686? Do you need to tell gcc the instructions?

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood GCC is already available for the architecture you want, in which case you want GCC as a cross-compiler (f.e. on a x86 machine with Windows, use gcc to cross-compile for ARM chips). You can see the targets for gcc [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html).

Note that in all likelihood you will need to compile GCC yourself with that target.

BTW, what is your target architecture?

Comment: Thanks for the responce, As said earlier my intention is to learn porting of gcc I am just curios to learn. I am not saying that gcc is not available for these architectures