# How to write your own code generator backend for gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I have created my very own (very simple) byte code language, and a virtual machine to execute it. It works fine, but now I'd like to use gcc (or any other freely available compiler) to generate byte code for this machine from a normal c program. So the question is, how do I modify or extend gcc so that it can output my own byte code? Note that I do NOT want to compile my byte code to machine code, I want to "compile" c-code to (my own) byte code.

I realize that this is a potentially large question, and it is possible that the best answer is "go look at the gcc source code". I just need some help with how to get started with this. I figure that there must be some articles or books on this subject that could describe the process to add a custom generator to gcc, but I haven't found anything by googling.

Comment: Go look at LLVM. GCC is known for being hard to extend.

Comment: this guide could help you: http://www.drdobbs.com/retargeting-the-gnu-c-compiler/184401529 “ An inside look on how to deploy the GNU C compiler to your platform of choice.” — a pretty good read, though I did not yet try to follow it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**It is hard work.**

For example I also design my own "architecture" with my own byte code and wanted to generate C/C++ code with GCC for it. This is the way how I make it:

1. At first you should read everything about porting in the [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/) of GCC.
2. Also not forget too read [GCC Internals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/).
3. Read many things about Compilers.
4. Also look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245481/porting-gcc-to-new-architectures) and the answers here.
5. Google for more information.
6. Ask yourself if you are really ready.
7. Be sure to have a very good cafe machine... you will need it.
8. Start to add machine dependet files to gcc.
9. Compile gcc in a cross host-target way.
10. Check the code results in the Hex-Editor.
11. Do more tests.
12. Now have fun with your own architecture :D

When you are finished you can use c or c++ only without os-dependet libraries (you have currently no running OS on your architecture) and you should now (if you need it) compile many other libraries with your cross compiler to have a good framework.

PS: [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) ([Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)) is easier to port... maybe you want to start there?

Comment: Some very practical advice here :) Thanks! Gcc seems to be a fearsome beast. I'll certainly take a look at LLVM as well. This project seems larger than I originally thought, but I'll give it a shot...

Comment: @pearcoding On which ground do you claim LLVM is easier to port than gcc? Did you attempt to port both and came to this conclusion, or did you use someone else's conclusion? If the latter, reference please. Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

I am busy porting gcc to an 8-bit processor we design earlier. I is kind of a difficult task for our machine because it is 8-bit and we have only one accumulator, but if you have more resources it can became easy. This is how we are trying to manage it with gcc 4.9 and using cygwin:

1. Download gcc 4.9 source
2. Add your architecture name to `config.sub` around line 250 look for `# Decode aliases for certain CPU-COMPANY combinations.` In that list add `| my_processor \`
3. In that same file look for `# Recognize the basic CPU types with company name.` add yourself to the list: `| my_processor-* \`
4. Search for the file `gcc/config.gcc`, in the file look for case ${target} it is around line 880, add yourself in the following way:

   ```
     ;;
   my_processor*-*-*)
     c_target_objs="my_processor-c.o"
     cxx_target_objs="my_processor-c.o"
     target_has_targetm_common=no
     tmake_file="${tmake_file} my_processor/t-my_processor"
     ;;
   ```
5. Create a folder `gcc-4.9.0\gcc\config\my_processor`
6. Copy files from an existing project and just edit it, or create your own from scratch. In our project we had copied all the files from the msp430 project and edited it all
7. You should have the following files (not all files are mandatory):

   - `my_processor.c`
   - `my_processor.h`
   - `my_processor.md`
   - `my_processor.opt`
   - `my_processor-c.c`
   - `my_processor.def`
   - `my_processor-protos.h`
   - `constraints.md`
   - `predicates.md`
   - `README.txt`
   - `t-my_processor`
8. create a path `gcc-4.9.0/build/object`
9. run `../../configure --target=my_processor --prefix=path for my compiler --enable-languages="c"`
10. make
11. make install
12. Do a lot of research and debugging.
13. Have fun.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes. Just out of curiousity, on what architecture did you try to port gcc? How well did you success? Did you also port binutils, or did you use an external assembler instead? How could you test full correct behaviour of the emitted code? Thanks.

Comment: @Bregalad we cross compiled from Linux to our own architecture, a very simple instruction set we designed. So the compiler lived on some Linux server. We abounded the project but learnt a lot. If I do it over I will spend more time learning gcc internals. We did not port binutils at all, but build our own assembler. Our archirecture was simple enough to take this route. I am sure there are better methods for testing emitted code, but we only evaluated the generated assembly code manually.

Comment: A lot dated, but a *good* answer. See also GCC's webpage: "[Extending and Contributing to GCC](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/contributewhy.html)", Wikipedia: "[GCC - Back-end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection#Back_end)", and the newest answers that [a search](https://www.google.com/search?q=backend+for+gcc%3F) would turn up; as over the years these type of Q&A's go out of date at least bi-annually.

Answer (score 4):

It's not as hard as all that. If your target machine is reasonably like another, take its RTL (?) definitions as a starting point and amend them, then `make compile test` through the bootstrap stages; rinse and repeat until it works. You probably don't have to write any actual code, just machine definition templates.

Comment: I did exactly this some time around 1990-91. The only thing I had to amend in the RTL was the location of the return value when it is floating-point. Very simple. Took longer to build than to implement.