# GCC - How to add support to a new architecture?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, porting

I am trying to learn how to port GCC to new architectures. Most tutorials say that I only have to create three files named `my_processor.c` `my_processor.h` and `my_processor.md`; however when running `./configure --target=my_processor` machine is not recognized.

Following an answer given in [How to write your own code generator backend for gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617215/how-to-write-your-own-code-generator-backend-for-gcc), I added my configuration in `config.sub` and `./configure` worked.

Unfortunately, when I use `make`, the terminal returns an error saying

```
checking if mkdir takes one argument... no
*** Configuration my_processor-unknown-none not supported
Makefile:4230: recipe for target 'configure-gcc' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-gcc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'objdir'
Makefile:905: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The problem seems to be due to a bad configuration in `gcc/config.gcc`, maybe because I added my architecture in a wrong place (there are multiple case ${target}, so not sure which choose) or because I am missing something.

The only information that I have found appears in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.2/gccint/Back-End.html, but it is not complete enough.

So, how could I do to avoid this error?

Comment: Yes, you need to edit more configuration files. You could check when recent backends were added to see what files they edited.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-cvs/2017-02/ see r245224 ... r245231 for the introduction of the RISCV port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Krister Walfridsson's blog](https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/08/writing-gcc-backend_4.html) has a detailed description of all the steps needed to create a new backend. The [first in the series](https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/08/the-structure-of-gcc-back-end.html) is about the 8 kinds of files to be changed or created. It's also suggested to follow the logic for a Moxie backend that might be easier to start with than risc-v.