# How to port C to a new architecture?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, architecture, port

Imagine that we have a single board computer, the CPU has it's own instruction set, assembly language, and without a Operating System(yet, thought we have a assembly command line shell), what should I do, in order to port C into that new computer? What do I need first? What should I set? Do I need to cross-compile on other working computers?

I know there's a quite close question in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245481/porting-gcc-to-new-architectures), But I do not wanted to port GCC, I'd like to port a even simple implementation of C, GCC toolkit is too fat for us.

Comment: So you want to write your own compiler? Or do you have an open compiler in mind which you want to port to a new architecture?

Comment: You will certainly start with cross-compilation, but your question is meaningless without naming a specific compiler.

Comment: @MatthiasB I wanted to make a compiler run on that architecture, any of them, but I do not wanted to run GCC first, because GCC set is too  big.

Comment: You could have a look at tinyc http://bellard.org/tcc/

Comment: The instruction set makes a big difference. And so does number and size (8-bit, 16-bit or 32-bit) of the registers. And also the amount of RAM (for variables and stack).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need to cross compile your C program for target CPU on any other Host machine. For that you need to find available toolchain for target architure on Host machine.

Comment: What should I do in order to cross compile the program?

Comment: As i said Find if vendor of target cpu provides any toolchain for any kind of host? If yes then use that. No then you have big task. Understand the Instruction set of target CPU and then transform you c program logic into that instaruction set

Comment: Only the assembly reference is released.