# Porting GCC to new architecture

Tags: linux, gcc, architecture, cross-compiling, porting

I am new to GCC and going to port GCC compiler to new architecture.

- Step 1 : **Implement GCC (gcc-4.6.1) for new architecture**
- Step 2 : **Implement binutils (binutils-2.21.1) for new architecture**
- Step 3 : ...

Now I am in step 1 and my problem is,
Can I build GCC without implementing binutils and others. Output likes "{target}-linux-elf-gcc" 
and need to get and check assembly output using following command;

> $ {new-machine}-linux-elf-gcc -S main.c

Comment: What you say "new machine" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: "new machine" means new architecture. Target processor is newly designed processor and not supported GCC yet.

Comment: @deeman Bootstrapping `gcc` to a new architecture is a question so broad that it defies reason.

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-05/msg00018.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245481/porting-gcc-to-new-architectures

Comment: You should first implement binutils, then port GCC!

Comment: Are you prepared to work a whole year on this (given that you are not familiar with GCC internals, which are difficult to grasp)?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Building GCC includes building libraries, like libgcc (which includes primitive operations not supported by CPU). But to build those libraries, you will need binutils.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your question correctly, you wanted to compile your version of GCC for a given Architecture.

Download binutils package, configure it and compile the same, Install this and have it ready to build the GCC.

Download the GCC version package which you are interested in and configure with parameters which clearly explains on target architecture and other details.
Refer this page for more configuration help: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html

> If you are building this GCC on your native machine, most likely a set of kernel headers for
>   your platform will be available and you don’t need to be concerned with headers.
>   But for cross-compiling, a set of kernel headers from a source tree configured for your target must be made available.

Sample configure, for native compiler:
./configure --prefix=PREFIX

For native cross-compiler:
./configure --target=powerpc-linux --prefix=/usr --with-headers=/usr/src/linux/include --enable-languages=c --disable-threads

Once you have built your GCC, later you need to build glibc, Using the newly generated GCC toolchain.

After this you should be able to compile any other packages using your newly created toolchain. 
If you want to compile a small test-program which has *less dependencies* in that test-program you can do so once you have the GCC ready.